# Robocopy ERROR 5. Access is denied

Tags: security, backup, windows-server-2012, robocopy

When using robocopy to backup data in a directory tree to a NAS, I keep getting **Error 5 - Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory. Access denied.** for folders which shouldn't return such error. The robocopy script is executed by a non-admin user called "backup" used specifically for backups which has Full access to all files and folders.

When executing the script most of the folders return an erro 5 whilst some others return an error 5.

The log follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 19 February 2017 17:01:15
   Source : F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\
     Dest : \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DATS /PURGE /MIR /R:10 /W:5 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\
                       2    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\01-11-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:16 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\01-11-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\01_09_2010\
        Modified           62899    Production Hours + Progress 01-09-2010.xlsx
                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\02-11-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:16 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\02-11-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\02_06_2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:16 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\02_06_2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\03-11-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:17 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\03-11-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\03_06_2010\
                       3    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\04_05_2010\
                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\06-10-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:18 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\06-10-2010\
Access is denied.


                       0    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\07-08-10\
2017/02/19 17:01:18 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\07-08-10\
Access is denied.


                       3    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\08-07-10\
2017/02/19 17:01:18 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\08-07-10\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\09-06-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:18 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\09-06-2010\
Access is denied.


                       5    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\10_06_2010\
                       3    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\12-10-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:19 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\12-10-2010\
Access is denied.


                       2    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\13_05_2010\
                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\15-07-10\
2017/02/19 17:01:19 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\15-07-10\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\15-09-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:19 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\15-09-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\17-08-10\
2017/02/19 17:01:19 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\17-08-10\
Access is denied.


                       3    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\17_06_2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:20 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\17_06_2010\
Access is denied.


                       2    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\19-10-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:20 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\19-10-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\20-10-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:20 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\20-10-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\20_05_2010\
                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\21-07-10\
2017/02/19 17:01:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\21-07-10\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\21-10-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\21-10-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\22-09-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\22-09-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\22-10-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\22-10-2010\
Access is denied.


                       2    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\23_06_2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\23_06_2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\25-10-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\25-10-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\27-10-2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:22 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\27-10-2010\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\27_05_2010\
                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\29-07-10\
2017/02/19 17:01:22 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\29-07-10\
Access is denied.


                       2    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\29-09-10\
2017/02/19 17:01:23 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\29-09-10\
Access is denied.


                       2    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\30-06-10\
2017/02/19 17:01:23 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\30-06-10\
Access is denied.


                       1    F:\files\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\Project Closure July 2010\
2017/02/19 17:01:23 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory \\nas\fooBack\fooDrive\Auto2\Archive\Dir1\Dir2\Project Closure July 2010\
Access is denied.



------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :        34         0         0         0         0         0
   Files :        15         1        14         0         0         0
   Bytes :   907.4 k    61.4 k   846.0 k         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:08   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:07


   Speed :              511373 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :              29.261 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : 19 February 2017 17:01:23
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

All files and folders involved allow Full access to the backup user executing the script.

I'm sure I'm missing something minor.

Thanks and I look forward to your help.

Answer (score 3):

That's usually caused by RoboCopy trying to backup the security settings for a file, and this causes some mismatch regarding the file permissions.

If you're running `robocopy /copy:datsou` (copies all attributes), `robocopy /sec` (equivalent to `/copy:dats`) or `robocopy /copyall` (equivalent to `/copy:datsou`), try replacing it by `robocopy /copy:dat`, which ignores the NTFS access control lists (the `copy:s` paramter) of the files you're copying. This is also handy when you explicitly don't want the NTFS ACLs to get copied, for example when replicating files between different domains.

More information regarding [RoboCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Answer (score 0):

I had to reboot (or dis- and reconnect?) the target share on the client where I invoked robocopy by yarcgui. The target smb/cifs share was an openindiana/solaris NAS which joined successfully to the ws2012 ADDC. The client is windows 10. The share was fully accessible to everyone, domain-admins and the current logged in user.